# Using a Batch File to Copy Desktop icons from %userprofile%\Desktop to %public%\Desktop

Tags: batch-file

I have searched and searched and can not figure this out.

What I am trying to do is after a user installs a particular program package, I want the icons installed with the package to be deleted and then I want my icons saved on our server (`T:\0CADD_14\_SetupDocs\AutoCAD 2014 - English.lnk`) to be placed in `%public%\Desktop`.

In the laymen world of copying files, i.e. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> / <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, I get the error message **Location is not available**. I can however copy that file to my desktop (`%userprofile%\Desktop`) and then move the files into `%public%\Desktop` but I have to click "Continue" as the admin to say this is okay.

I am guessing the code is getting hung up on that admin part but haven't been able to figure out how to get past that in the batch file, this is my code

```
DEL /Q /F "C:\Users\Public\Desktop\AutoCAD 2014 - English.lnk"
DEL /Q /F "C:\Users\Public\Desktop\Civil 3D 2014 Imperial.lnk"
COPY "T:\0CADD_14\_SetupDocs\AutoCAD 2014 - English.lnk" "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\AutoCAD 2014 - English.lnk"
COPY "T:\0CADD_14\_SetupDocs\Civil 3D 2014 Imperial.lnk" "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\Civil 3D 2014 Imperial.lnk"
MOVE %USERPROFILE%\Desktop\Civil 3D 2014 Imperial.lnk "%public%\Desktop\Civil 3D 2014 Imperial.lnk"
MOVE %USERPROFILE%\Desktop\AutoCAD 2014 - English.lnk "%public%\Desktop\AutoCAD 2014 - English.lnk"
```

For whatever reason "Run as administrator" isn't working either. Other post I have read talk about disabling the UAC to work around this issue but I'd rather not do that.

Comment: What are the security settings on the public desktop? Is it set to read only?

Comment: You can not actually circumvent the UAC prompt without disabling the UAC. That is kind of the point of UAC. Otherwise there would be no point in it, because then the malicious hacker could also circumvent the UAC with the same strategy. However since the installer is elevated out the installer calling in the batch script then thay will be done with the same UAC prompt. YJay pr use a user with high enough privileges by default.

Comment: I just went and look those, for my profile they are at the lowest setting.

Comment: Why are you copying the files to `"%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\AutoCAD 2014 - English.lnk"` then moving them to `"%public%\Desktop\Civil 3D 2014 Imperial.lnk"`? Also, the first directories in your `MOVE` commands are not wrapped with quotation marks.

Comment: If I try to copy files manually, directly from my server to the '%public%\Desktop' I get a message of "Location not available" from Windows 7. I added the quotes and it sort of worked in that the shortcuts were deleted and the new shortcuts placed in the '%USERPROFILE%\Desktop' and that was from doing "run as administrator" on the batch file. If I run it again, then it was move the shortcuts to '%public%\Desktop' but I get the lock symbol on the icon.